# Create Mock for constructor using jest-typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to create a mock for constructor using jest for typescript. I have a class , say, **Vehicle** as :

```
export class vehicle{
  engineNumber : number;
  constructor(engNumber: number){
    this,=.engineNUmber = engNumber;
  }
  getEngine(){
    return new Engine()
  }
}
```

And let class **Engine** be :

```
export class Engine{
  constructor(){
    return 'this-is-engine-for-vehicle';
  }
}
```

I want to create mock for Engine.constructor. I have tried using 
`engine.constructor = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mock-engine')` but it is not getting called. I should not mock the class or getEngine(). Please help me with this.